# Managing dependency versions of services in Micro service architecture

Tags: deployment, microservices, dependency-management

In my current team we are running close to 70-80 micro services on cloud. The challenge what we face during each release is managing the dependency build versions of each service. Not all micro service
have changes for each release so we cannot update the versions for each service blindly.

It takes considerable amount of time to understand the current scope of release and change the dependency versions for only those services leaving rest unchanged. Is there a better way of managing the dependencies for releases. I am looking mainly for any open source tool or process which can be used for our team.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45177810/569662

Comment: Could you give some more info how you deploy the service in the Cloud? Which cloud do you use and which services? Why do I ask this? The reason is that you can keep track of versions of services in AWS ECS Cluster for each service(actually the service helps you doing this).
Also for development purposes do you use docker with your own Registry or some platform for it?

Comment: We are using plain CF with AWS as infrastructure. The entire devops is handled by a separate team so its not possible for us to go and check the versions of the services on cloud. We just make sure we have right builds in the artifactory. We don't use docker.