# Notifying microservices on endpoint upgrade

Tags: flask, swagger, microservices

Assuming that all my microservices are documented with Swagger. If I have an endpoint in a microservice that I need to upgrade (from v1 to v2 for example and the return payload will change). Are there any tools out there to find all clients (i.e other microservices) using this endpoint to ensure a smooth upgrade and ensure that they all use the v2 endpoint?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Microservices Deployment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45170527/microservices-deployment)